# How do I keep my video div/container/wrapper from moving when I zoom in and out?

Tags: html, video, width, containers, wrapper

Here's what's happening. I dont want my video to be full width. I want it a specific width. When I change the width the container sends the video to the left side. Then when I put in the middle it appears to be fine....until you zoom in and out and the div/container/wrapper moves the video.

How can I solve this?

How do I keep my video div/container/wrapper from moving when I zoom in and out?

The video is directly under the navigation bar so I'm sure it has something to do with the header's div/wrapper width. Please help.

```
HTML
```

-->

```
  <div  class="video-background" id="video-background">
    <video  loop="loop" autoplay poster="{{ 'home-placeholder.jpg' | asset_url }}" width="100%">
        <source src="{{ 'home.mp4' | asset_url }}" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="{{ 'home.webm' | asset_url }}" type="video/webm">
        <source src="{{ 'home.ogg' | asset_url }}" type="video/ogg">
        <img alt="" src="{{ 'home-placeholder.jpg' | asset_url }}" width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below">
    </video>
    <a href="#home-bubbles" class="skip-video" title="Scroll Down">Scroll Down</a>

  </div>
```

And CSS

```
div.video-background {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*position: fixed;
    top: 96px;*/
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    /*z-index: -1; */
    margin-top:96px;
      position:relative;
}

div.video-background video {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: -2 !important;
}

div.video-background > div {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

div.video-background .circle-overlay {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -590px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
}

div.video-background .ui-video-background {
    display: none !important;
}

.index .sub-footer {
    margin-top:0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found an answer to this or a fix.

I tried three different things.

1. Setting different px values at different screen intervals

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1180px){
    div.video-background video {
      
      width:1000px;
      
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 801px){
    div.video-background video {
      
      width:700px;
      
   }
}
```

Also tried

```css
width:auto;
```

Didn't do the trick.

2. I then tried em

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 75em){

    div.video-background video {
      
      width:50em;
      
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 65em){
    div.video-background video {
      
      width:30em;
      
   }
}
```

Worked better but didn't solve it.

3. I finally tried vh setting width and height as vh

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1180px){
    div.video-background video {
      
      width:60vh;
      height:60vh;
      
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 801px){
    div.video-background video {
      
      width:40vh;
      height:40vh;
   }
}
```

And that fixed the issue. Please take these values with a grain of salt as they do not really represent the actual numbers I used. But hopefully this helps you in the future when dealing with browser zoom, overlapping elements, and moving divs.